# Autosubmit for form and .appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want the combobox to my self send in form, I have no problem there it succeeds to do with .change, the problem is that these combobox need them in another div outside the container form.

This is the code I'm working on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

  $('.form-item-sort-bef-combine,.views-widget-per-page').appendTo('.view-header');

  $('#edit-items-per-page, #edit-sort-bef-combine').change(function() {

    // Submit the form
    //$('.block-views').find('form').submit();
    //$('form#views-exposed-form-vacation-rentals-kiawah-rentals-home').submit();

   $(this).parents('form').submit();

  });
});
```

Everything works until active .AppendTo

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the html? Also I believe the syntax for calling multiple classes with jQuery requires that the classes be separated by comma in different strings such as this:

```
$('.form-item-sort-bef-combine', '.views-widget-per-page').appendTo('.view-header');
```

The way you have it currently won't work I believe

Comment: The appendTo if he is doing with the current syntax.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to add the string, '.form-item-sort-bef-combine,.views-widget-per-page' to the end of the view header? Or are you actually trying to add those as a class? If so there is a different jquery function

Comment: I trying to add the string, '.form-item-sort-bef-combine,.views-widget-per-page' to the end of the view header. But the problem is not that, the problem is sending data to the form when those two  combobox are out of form

Comment: What do you mean sending data to the form? What comboboxes? Can we see more code?